# Python search-engine interface for SQL?

Tags: python, sql, parsing, code-generation, search-engine

I am writing an SQL generator in Python, for converting search queries such as:

```js
foo=='bar' and car=='foo' and (jar=='h o r' or jar==null)
```

Into the following SQL code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_coo T0, tbl_coup T1
WHERE T0.foo=='bar' AND T1.car=='foo'
      AND (T1.jar=='h o r' OR T1.jar==NULL);
```

Most of the way implemented:

- Find table name given  column name (set-cover problem) #done
- Parse query so I can rewrite it with table name #mostlydone
- Generate SQL from reparsed query #next

#### Considering how general purpose this is; has someone done it already? - Link?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. You can use HayStack (http://haystacksearch.org/) with Django.

Comment: Thanks, worried that I was reinventing which is why I asked here. I should note that I am using Bottle; and have my frontend completely on the client-side (so can't use Python there). Can you recommend a non-Django solution?